# Usage of `void()` in a comma-separated list?

Tags: c++

I was looking into a piece of code written by others when I saw this:

```
a(), void(), b();
```

where both `a` and `b` are instances of a user-defined template class, which is intended to act like a function by overloading `operator()` that returns the calling instance itself.

Part of the class:

```
template <typename T>
class SomeClass{
    public:
    SomeClass& operator()(void);
    const SomeClass& operator()(void) const;
}
```

The return statements for both overloads are the following:

```
template <typename T>
SomeClass<T>& SomeClass<T>::operator()(void){
    // do stuff
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
const SomeClass<T>& SomeClass<T>::operator()(void) const{
    // do stuff
    return *this;
}
```

What does the `void()` between them do? I feel it strange.

Comment: No authoritative answer can be given without more context. C++'s grammar is quite complicated. For example 'X *p' could mean either multipliation, or a pointer declaration. You need to provide more context.

Comment: Lots of BS in the comments thus far. Comments are not for guessing answers. Correct answer below.

Comment: This is a valid question and shouldn't be getting downvotes.

Comment: Actually, @Bathsheba, given the additional context posted, the answer below is not correct.

Comment: @Simple Actually, it should get downvotes, as I do not see in his code what is being asked

Comment: @BЈовић did you not read the last sentence or the title of the question?

Comment: @Simple No, I am looking for `a(), void(), b();` in the code that is posted. It is nowhere to be found. No strange `void()` anywhere to be seen. Closing the question.

Comment: Where is `void()` in the posted code?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `void()` prevents an overloaded `operator,` from being called (where one of the parameters is of the type `SomeClass<T>`), as such an overload can't have a parameter of type `void`.

You will most often see this used in templates, and is used in variadic pack expansions:

```
// C++11/14:
int unpack[] = {0, (do_something(pack), void(), 0)...};
// C++17 (fold expression):
(void(do_something(pack)), ...);
```

Where an overloaded `operator,` could ruin the [sequencing guarantees](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) of the language.

Comment: Wow. I've never heard that someone overloads `operator,`.

Comment: @iBug - This is C++, we can overload everything. EVERYTHING!

Comment: Not quite yet: the member selection operator and ternary conditional operators being important exceptions. (Although doesn't Stroustrup want to relax the former?)

Comment: @Bathsheba - That proposal fell through, too much weirdness comes along with it, IIRC. Still, it's a damn impressive feat to make almost any expression context dependent :)

Comment: @StoryTeller: I guess we got `operator""` in compensation.

Comment: @iBug: fun fact : I did it to manage date/time format depending on the language. `(std::cout, lang::fr) << time;`.
It was funny. :-p

Comment: So at last, are these six the only operators that can't be overloaded? `:: . .* ?: sizeof typeid` (double-colon, dot, dot-asterisk, ternary, sizeof, typeid)

Comment: `decltype` as well.

Comment: @iBug - If you throw in `sizeof` than you should also bring up `alignof` and `decltype`.

Comment: @Caduchon By overloading `std::ostream& operator,(std::ostream&, LangType)` (where `LangType` is the type of `lang::fr`)?

Comment: There's also been a proposal to make `void` a regular old type (i.e. like `int`), which would stop this trick from working, and you'd be unable to protect yourself from overloaded `operator,`

Comment: @Simple Naw, you'd just do `void(a()), void(b())` instead.

Comment: @StoryTeller Damn impressive feat, yes. Sanity lies in another direction, though (imho).

Comment: @Simple If you have to defend against overloaded `operator,`, you are working with the wrong people, imho.

Comment: @cmaster you would do it when you are the author of some generic function in some library. It needs to work correctly in the presence of an overloaded `operator,` in the same way the standard library needs to work correctly in the presence of `operator&` or `operator&&` or `operator||`.

Comment: @Simple But, if that `operator,` is present, **shouldn't** I be using that to use the type the way that it's supposed to be? Saying `foo(), void(), bar()` is like saying: I know, you may want to do something special in this situation, but I'm not going to allow you to. Don't understand me wrong, I understand the problems of not using `, void(),` as well. I just want to point out that both `,` and `, void(),` can be considered wrong in the presence of an overloaded `operator,`. And, unless I know the precise `operator,` that I would be using, *I cannot make a sound decision*.

Comment: @cmaster Typical generic code uses `,` for its built-in meaning: evaluate the left, discard the result, evaluate the right, and return it. The "discard the result" part is part of the intended behavior; the comma is merely a tool to combine multiple disparate expressions into a single one where syntactically required. In the `unpack` example, the intended action is simply `do_something(pack.[0]); do_something(pack.[1]); ...` (using some imaginary syntax to index a pack); note that the results of these expressions are implicitly discarded. The `void()` trick merely made the discarding explicit.